# sortedArrayUsingComparator returning incorrect results

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an array which has a set of timestamps (as strings) and they are in sorted order. I just want to sort them again and see if the same list is returned (reason is I'll be dealing with further timestamps stored out of order and will need to sort them). Here is my dates array where timestamps are basically strings:

```
(
"Jun 18, 2014 12:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 5:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 5:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 5:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 9:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 9:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:45:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:45:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:45:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:45:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 5:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 5:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 9:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 9:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 9:45:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:45:00 PM"
)
```

The above array is in sorted timestamps. Now, if I re-sort them in ascending order, they should give me the same results I suppose BUT I am getting out of order results. I just don't understand why I am seeing such a behavior:
Here is the output I am getting:

```
sorted dates = (
"Jun 18, 2014 12:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 9:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 5:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 9:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 5:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:30:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 5:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:45:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:00:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 5:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 6:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 9:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:15:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 5:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 7:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 8:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 9:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 10:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:30:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:45:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 2:45:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 3:45:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 4:45:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 9:45:00 PM",
"Jun 18, 2014 11:45:00 PM"
)
```

For example, why would "Jun 18, 2014 12:15:00 AM", be displayed after "Jun 18, 2014 1:00:00 AM"? I just don't get this part!!

Here is my code:

```
-(void)sortDates {
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];

NSLog(@"%@", xAxisDataWithDate);
NSArray *sortedTimes = [xAxisDataWithDate sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2)
{
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2];
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
NSLog(@"sorted dates = %@", sortedTimes);
}
```

I also wrote a sample program with a subset containing these dates and it seems to give me the wrong result when 1:00:00 AM is present in the array (1:00:00 AM should have been stored AFTER 12:00:00 AM):

```
-(void)sortDates {
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];

NSMutableArray *times = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Jun 19, 2014 11:45:00 PM", @"Jun 18, 2014 1:00:00 AM", @"Jun 18, 2014 12:15:00 AM",@"Jun 18, 2014 12:00:00 AM", nil];
NSArray *sortedTimes = [times sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2)
{
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2];
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
NSLog(@"sorted dates = %@", sortedTimes);
}
```

Output:

```
sorted dates = (
"Jun 18, 2014 1:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:15:00 AM",
"Jun 19, 2014 11:45:00 PM"
)
```

I can't figure out why I am getting out of order results w.r.t NSMutableArray *xAxisDataWithDate and w.r.t NSMutableArray *times! Kindly help me in this regard! Appreciated.

Comment: You should be using "hh" for the hour, since you're using 1-12 with AM/PM. "HH" is for 0-23. Also, be sure to set the locale of the date format to some standard locale (probably `[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]`) rather than letting it pick up the system locale, since that will vary. All of that said, you should probably be using date objects to begin with, rather than strings.

Comment: Also, try logging the `NSDate` objects that your formatter gives for two strings which end up sorted incorrectly relative to each other. See how it's interpreting those strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a wrong format, the time appears to be in 12 hour format, change your format to `MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a` note [lowercase "h"](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

```
"Jun 18, 2014 12:00:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 12:15:00 AM",
"Jun 18, 2014 1:00:00 AM",
"Jun 19, 2014 11:45:00 PM"
```

More importantly, you should convert strings to dates prior to comparison, `sortedArray…` is using merged sort, therefore you will convert string to dates `n log n` times instead of `n` times